# Is it possible to connect Aws Iot with EMQX (that's using SparkPlug B specification) and have the messages decoded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, mqtt-sparkplug

I want to connect to an EMQX broker (using sparkplug b) and subscribe to messages using Aws Iot (acting as a  bridge to other AWS services). I can do that with EMQX but the EMQX I'm using as source is using Sparplug B specification.

I know I can create an EC2 machine to act as a router (decode the messages first and then send to other AWS services) but I didn't want to self manage the EC2. Are there other alternatives?

Thanks a lot

I received the encrypted messages on AWS Iot (connected to EMQX) but wasn't able to route them (encoded) using the rules in Aws Iot.
Then I created an ec2, connect to the EQMX as client, that acts as router/decoder (python) and published them to Aws Iot (which in this case was just to test, but I could have sent them to other AWS service.